# How to set delay between change routs

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I tring to do animation for change site language when i clicking on link.
When i clicking on rout-link need set delay before change DOM content. It is possible?

```
mounted (){      
  this.showLanguage()

},
beforeDestroy (){
  this.hideLanguage()
}
```

logics:

1. elements hide
2. Vue change DOM content
3. element showing

but Vue changing content before hide element.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello! Please add in all the necessary code so we can replicate the issue. Without it, we will be unable to help. Please also try to clearly state what you are expecting the code to do and what it is actually doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I show how i can do it.
Need use router hooks

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
   // your code
   next () // will change rout
})
```

Answer (score 1):

While you can set this up using your own solution, you may be better served by using the built-in [`transition`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitioning-Single-Elements-Components) or [`transition-group`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Transitions)

the documentation on the vue page is quite extensive. Just make sure you use mode 'out-in' to have the `out` animation finish before the `in` animation starts.

Comment: thanks, i already use it, but my animation soooo specific.
Anyway i found solution.